# How to use Jason with JEdit on Mac

Tags: java, agent, jedit

I'm just starting out with Jason (agent-oriented language) and having problems running some code. It gives me the following error:[image]

I'm pretty new to this so not really sure what to do next. This is the path information from Jason:
[image]

I can tell the problem is related to the path of the Java Home, but I don't know what to change it to. I'm using Mac by the way.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: can you check what is output of `echo $(/usr/libexec/java_home)` command?

Comment: The output is this: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_221.jdk/Contents/Home`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the problem of "The path to the jason.jar file (...) was not correctly set:...", in "Plugins -> Plugins Options -> Jason", you have to set the path to "jason-X.Y.jar" location. You pointed it to "jedit.jar", just change it to "/libs/jason-2.4.jar".

You also may be asked to fix ant path. In this case, point it to the folder "/libs".